# Usages for Worksheet_SelectionChange and Workbook_SheetSelectionChange events

Tags: vba, excel

As far as I understand it they do the same thing, but while

```
Worksheet_SelectionChange
```

is triggered every time selection is changed on **a single** worksheet,

```
Workbook_SheetSelectionChange
```

is triggered every time selection is changed in **any** worksheet in the workbook.

***Are there any other differences between these events?***

Comment: That's precisely it. If you want the same code triggered for all (or several) sheets, it's often easier to use the Workbook level event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single parameter supplied by the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event macro is the cell or range of cells that have just been selected, e.g. *Target*. The `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` supplies that but adds the worksheet where the selection was made with *Sh*.

If you want the same thing to happen on multiple worksheets (not necessarily all of them), use `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` and deal with the *Sh* parameter. This also centralizes your code so that modifications do not have to be repeated in several places. If you are only planning on reacting to selection changes on a single worksheet, use that worksheet's `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event macro on its own sheet code page.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you answered your own question.

If you want Change events to happen specific to ONE sheet, then put `Worksheet_SelectionChange` into the Sheet's module.

If you want Change events to happen on every sheet in the book, then put `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` into the Book's module.

Note, if you only want say 3 of 5 sheets triggering, you could run a check at the beginning of the Workbook_Change event to check for Sheet.Name